# Can't install Imagick for PHP on Debian

Tags: php, imagick

Pulling my hair out.  PHP built from source, everything working.  Now need to install imagick and can't get it installed.

I am running Debian on kernel 3.7.1 with PHP 5.3.20 (the last version my app supports, cannot go to PHP 5.4).

```
pecl install imagick
...
checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... found in /usr/bin/Wand-config
checking if ImageMagick version is at least 6.2.4... configure: error: no. You need at least Imagemagick version 6.2.4 to use Imagick.
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/configure --with-imagick' failed
```

Yet, I have version 6.7.7 installed:

```
# convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2012-11-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

I also tried installing the latest beta (pecl install imagick-beta), same result.  Also tried an old version 2.3.0, same result.  Also tried downloading source, phpize, and configure -- same result.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Wouldn't that be something for http://serverfault.com/?

Answer (score 18):

I was finally able to solve this myself.  I ended up doing:

```
apt-get remove graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat imagemagick imagemagick-common
apt-get autoremove
```

Then:

```
apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

And finally was able to get imagick installed via pecl:

```
pecl install imagick-beta
```

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question! Helped me out!

Comment: I had the same struggle, installing the stable version from PECL produced issues during make install and did not complete - in result the installation was not complete and I couldnt use it. I read that it has to do with PHP5.4 compatibility (I use 5.4.4) so I tried pecl install imagick-3.1.0RC2 and it worked! :) It's good to update ghostscript by that occasion as well to ensure proper cooperation with IM.

Comment: I was able to install `pecl install imagick` (not beta) on wheezy after just doing `apt-get install libmagickwand-dev`.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I didn't need to remove those packages but the key was indeed installing imagick-beta rather than the current. even Two years later. Thanks!

Comment: ¡and don't forget to add `extension=imagick.so` to your `php.ini`!

Comment: I didn't need to remove or uninstall anything.  I using ran the `sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev`.  This was on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.